How to compile programs in docker and print the output to the front-end screen
I am working on a project where I need to run code within a Docker container, connect this container to a sandbox environment, and then return the execution output to the user. My goal is to ensure a secure and isolated execution environment while providing real-time feedback.
Here are the key steps I am looking to achieve:
Start a Docker container: This container should host the execution environment for running user-provided code.
Connect the container to a sandbox: The sandbox will provide the necessary isolation and security for running potentially untrusted code.
Execute the code inside the container: Run the user-provided code within this isolated environment.
Capture and return the output: Collect the output of the code execution and send it back to the user in real-time or near real-time.
I have some specific questions:
What are the best practices for securely connecting a Docker container to a sandbox environment?
Which tools or frameworks are recommended for managing the sandbox and ensuring secure code execution?
How can I efficiently capture and return the execution output to the user, considering performance and security?
Any advice, tutorials, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to create a docker container using JS by referring to a YouTube video but while doing the frontend I got errors the frontend was done in ReactJS but I have less knowledge to ReactJS.
Can anyone help me out in this, and I am expecting a container running the code using sandbox environment and after compiling the container should be deleted and while compiling a new code the docker has to create a new container.

A Docker container is probably not secure enough to run truly untrusted code.  Dynamically launching containers is itself tricky, so you're trying to handle code that might be launching various sorts of attacks in a context where you have unrestricted root-level access to the host system.
